# Use result of a query as a table in another query

Tags: jira, jql

I want to create a filter that find stories that are not linked in any way with the result of a query (filter 17138). I thought I could use the result of the filter 17138 as a "data table" with tickets I don't want to be linked to but it doesn't work. This is my query :

`issue not in childIssuesOf(filter(17138)) AND issue not in linkedIssues(filter(17138))`

Can you help me please ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't use it directly because Jira does not have that feature out-of-box.

If you have ScriptRunner plugin in your Jira instance, you may use [JQL Functions](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html) that are created for that purpose.

Also, there are some other plugins that may help you. Just search for "nested jql queries" in Atlassian marketplace or Google.